# Circumvent the non-standard behaviour of __getattr__ in a Cython extension class

Tags: python, cython, getattr, getattribute

I am writing code, which I want to work both with vanilla Python and as part of a Cythonized module. I have a cdef class that I want to behave normally, but on which I want to override the behaviour of `__getattr__` (for undefined attributes). In Python this is simple, however Cython does not behave up to spec:

```py
@cython.cclass
class Test:
    field: cython.declare(object, visibility='public')

    def __init__(self):
        self.field = 24

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return 42
```

The expression `Test().field`, in Python, returns 24, as it should, and `Test().anything_else` gives `42`. In Cython, `Test().field` returns `42` as `__getattr__` is treated as if it was a `__getattribute__`. I do not want my object to have dynamic fields, I merely want to override the behaviour of the `.` operator for when a property is not found, as in vanilla Python.

I know I can define `__getattr__` as:

```py
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item == 'field':
        return self.field
    return 42
```

But once you get a few properties this becomes tedious.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You need to use `=`, not `:`, with `cython.declare`.

Comment: (Although even with the typo, I can't reproduce the behavior you say you're getting.)

Comment: At least on Cython 3.0.0 and Python 3.10.8 I do have the problem, however removing the typo fixes it. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noticed by @user2357112 in the comment my example contains a typo in the use of `cython.declare`, it should use `=` not `:`:

```py
@cython.cclass
class Test:
    field = cython.declare(object, visibility='public')

    def __init__(self):
        self.field = 24

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return 42
```

This fixes the problem for me.